# Cannot link to a library no way...VS 2010 lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, import

I can successfuly build and use a library. The later only if both the library and the other project is in the same solution....
I copied the isam.lib isam.dll  isam.exp isam.h under a folder called lib...

Then i created a new solution..

Set linker -> Input to use my isam.lib ...  Building fails, cant find that file...
Set VC++ Directories   Include Directories and Library Directories to the lib folder...

Build is successful..

Also i set path for C/C++ General   Additional include Directories
Set Linker General Additional library directories

Build is ok....

Then i include my isam file..

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <isam.h>

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        isopen("lamogio",2);
        return 0;
    }
```

Building fails...

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl isopen(char const *,int)" (_*imp*?isopen@@YAHPBDH@Z) referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\Parhs\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testdll2\testdll2\testdll2.obj testdll2

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Parhs\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testdll2\Debug\testdll2.exe    1   1   testdll2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's assume you told the linker to link to isam.lib with the Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies setting.  Then the possible cause of the linker error is that you wrote the isam code in C and you are using it in a C++ program.  You have to tell the compiler that the code was written in C:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C" {
    #include <isam.h>
}
```

The more typical solution is to put that in the isam.h file so that it is usable either way.  Like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

// The declarations
//...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: yes it is in C..The problem is that it wasnt started by me.. and i dont have a clue.. how he set it to C!...However extern c did the magic!!! I dont know why the sample programs included in solution didnt use extern "C" and work... I tried to create an empty win32 project but got the same error.. Is there any trick to set it to C by default?? I copied the whole tiny sample program from the samples that used the library but got the same error(when not in that solution!),however with extern it works....any idea?

Comment: Project templates in Visual Studio always enable C++ compilation by default.  That can be changed, simply by renaming your source code file to .c instead of .cpp.  Or with the /Tc compile option.  You'll get hassle from precompiled headers when you do so however.  I'd recommend you use this solution and continue to explore the Wild World of C++ programming.

Comment: Nice answer. (Hans Passant)++

Comment: i have no clue what are you talking about! I tried without extern changing to .c but got lots of problems... so i'll stick to extern "C"